# Capistrano3 deploy fails after migrating the server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, ssh, capistrano

I am using Capistrano 3. In the past I could successfully deploy to my server.

Now the server migrated and has new parameters:

- SSH Access (I updated SSH credentials and made sure that I can connect without password using `authorized_keys`)
- Deploy Dir (I updated `staging.rb` accordingly along with SSH Credentials)
- Now `cap` could connect to my new server so the Auth seemed fine.

#### Problems with `current` directory

However, I got an Error when using `cap staging deploy`:

```
SSHKit::Command::Failed: if test ! -d /var/www/my-project/subdomains/dev/current; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/www/my-project/subdomains/dev/current'" 1>&2; false; fi exit status: 1
```

I checked and the curiously the `current` directory was still there (migrated along with the rest). I deleted the `current` directory because this will be created on the deploy (I thought then).

On the next deploy I got the same error. So I did some googling and I ended up adding the following hook:

```
# Had to insert this hook after migrating the server
# Maybe this can be removed after the first successful deployment
after 'deploy:set_current_revision', 'deploy:symlink:release'
```

I think this is not a very clean approach but from then on the `current` directory was created and I got a little farther with `cap staging deploy`.

Now whenever I setup Capistrano I am amazed how painless it works but now since I have moved to another server I keep running into issues.

I wonder:

- Is there a new way to configure the environment in `deploy.rb` or `staging|production.rb` respectively?
- Do I have to delete existing shared files (e.g. bundler, tmp, pids etc.) or the current directory when I am on a new environment?

Comment: did you run `$ cap install` ?

Comment: @itsnikolay Yes I did, and I have been using capistrano3 with that project for months. But now on the new server everything seems to be broken.

Comment: take a look on the directory permission for `deployer` user, does he have rights to write in the directory (`$ ls -la`).

Comment: I do have the permission and all the files seem to be in place.

Comment: could you upload a output of running `cap staging deploy` command, on `gist.github.com` for example ?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix my deploy and I am not sure which of the steps I took were really required. 
I documented the solution in this SO Post: [Bundler in deployment mode does not find Gems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26146273/bundler-in-deployment-mode-does-not-find-gems)