# Bundler in deployment mode does not find Gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, bundler, rbenv

I was heavily struggling with my Capistrano Setup, when my Hoster migrated the server:

[Capistrano3 deploy fails after migrating the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26146080/capistrano3-deploy-fails-after-migrating-the-server)

One thing I ran into that used to work just fine on the old machine and now seems to be a mess is bundler:

I could successfully run bundler through Capistrano:

```
cap staging bundler:install
```

This resulted in the following command on the server

```
/usr/bin/env bundle install --binstubs \ 
/var/www/mydomain.com/subdomains/dev/shared/bin \
--path /var/www/mydomain.com/subdomains/dev/shared/bundle \
--without development test \
--deployment
```

But now when I ran my server `cap staging deploy:start_passenger` which results in the following:

```
/usr/bin/env passenger start --socket tmp/passenger.socket -e staging -d
```

Then I got the error in my log file, that Rake was missing:

```
Could not find rake-10.2.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
<pre>  /var/www/mydomain.com/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize&#39;
```

What is very weird, is the fact that the ruby version `2.1.2`(the one I really use)  shows up with `2.1.0. I have no visible reference to`2.1.0` in my project, and my Gemfile contains:

```
ruby '2.1.2'
```

Since  RBENV is used on the server I can run `rbenv versions` which shows me:

```
  system
* 2.1.2 (set by /var/www/mydomain.com/.rbenv/version)
```

So where does that weird `2.1.0` come from and how can I make sure that my server has all the dependencies it requires.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to deploy my application on the new server.

These steps were required to do it. However since I fought with it for a few hours some of it might be redundant:

- `gem install bundler && rbenv rehash`: This is required since `bundler` is one of the gems that I need **outside** of the Rails App context in terms of dependencies.
- Another one is `gem install passenger && rbenv rehash`
- I am now using https://github.com/capistrano/rbenv but for this I had to wipe RVM from my system, which was a step I wasn't too enthusiastic of doing.
- I had to make sure the current symlink was created so I added this to the `deploy.rb`

  ```
  after 'deploy:set_current_revision', 'deploy:symlink:release'
  ```
- I had to delete some of the shared directories:

  ```
  rm -fr bin
  rm -fr shared/bundle/
  rm -fr bundle
  ```